# Joomla 3.1 modificar header de un componente, que hereda del template

Tags: css, template, joomla3

Buenas tengo una web en Joomla 3.1 a la que quiero realizar un cambio especifico. Por ejemplo el componente contact poder cambiarle el css, para que no herede de la plantilla el header y el footer, sino que tengan un footer y header personalizado en estructura contenido y estilos.

Que archivos debo modificar para realizar el cambio?

gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de lograr eso, te nombraré las 3 que se me ocurren:

1.- cambiar el `index.php` dentro del template

Aquí, con:

```
$component = $app->input->getCmd('option');
```

Obtienes el nombre del componente, entonces solo necesitas hacer un `if` para cambiar el header

```
if($component == "com_contact"){
  //header personalizado
}
else{
  //header normal
}
```

---

2.- Puedes crear otro archivo similar a `ìndex.php`, que se llame `contacto.php`, en donde básicamente colocas lo mismo que en `ìndex.php` pero cambiando el header y el footer

---

3.- Si el header y el footer son módulos, puedes ir a "Extensiones->modulos", luego a la pestaña "Asignación de menú" y desactivarlos para ciertas páginas. Así mismo puedes crear un header y footer personalizado y solo activarlos para esas mismas páginas.

Evidentemente tienes que tener el `com_contact` ingresado a alguno de los menús.

Comment: Gracias, cambie el index del template como mencionaste y funciono!! Saludos